# Why is "cabal update" so slow and could I do it manually?

Tags: haskell, cabal

When running `cabal update`, it takes so long time to download `00-index.tar.gz` from [hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/index.tar.gz), howver, when I download it from chrome, it is just a 9M file and the downloading finishes soon.

so, why is `cabal update` so slow, and could I improve the performance by, for example manually download the files?

as for the version of cabal I am using, it is:

> cabal-install version 1.22.6.0 using version 1.22.4.0 of the Cabal
>   library

Comment: I assume `cabal update` does more than just download the tar ball. It likely also unpacks it, compares it's contents to your current contents, cleans up nicely after itself...

Comment: well, it just get stuck at the downloading stage...it just donloaded 100K after tens of miniutes.

Comment: If you're using an old version of cabal, you might be [hitting this bug](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2013-December/021771.html).

Comment: Post your version of `cabal`. Run `cabal --version`

Comment: cabal --version 
```
cabal-install version 2.2.0.0
compiled using version 2.2.0.1 of the Cabal library

```

Answer (score 2):

As a comment points out -- there was a bug in old versions of `cabal-install` that slowed things down considerably. Furthermore, modern versions try to not use the native `HTTP` library, but instead use external `curl` or `wget` binaries which are very efficient and more full-featured in terms of support for proxies, etc.